# Ordering Google accounts

Tags: google-account, google

Recently I created some new Google accounts, which messed up my ordering (Ex: /u/3 > /u/7).

I was wondering if I could change this ordering in the URL, as /u/1 - /u/3 are all accounts that I rarely use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What works for me is to [sign out](https://accounts.google.com/Logout) from /u/1 - /u/3, and the new account, and then sign in with the new account. It automatically gets the lowest available number.